# canvas Performance of drawImage: many small images vs few large

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, performance

I was wondering if there are any benchmarks or clues about whether its better to draw one large image or call drawImage more often for fewer images.

Example:

I have a canvas of ~1600x1000 (when Fullscreen) and an Image that size. I draw this image onto my canvas each frame (hence I can save ctx.clearRect()). It has about 6 objects that I could easily draw each on its own in multiple drawImage-calls, but I'd need to do clearRect(); every frame.

Which is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the 6 objects and / or the full canvas?
If the 6 objects are tiny, there's a chance that it might be faster. If they cover the canvas, together, then a single call will probably be faster

Comment: use layered canvases if your background doesn't change. See here : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/      look for "use multiple layered canvases for complex scenes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing a few larger images will perform better than many small images.

It's the actual `drawImage` that causes the performance hit. Calling this the least number of times will yield better performace.

As per the comments, it's likely you will have better performance using multiple canvases. It really does depend what you're trying to achieve before determining if this is actually necessary. If we're just talking 6 images, I probably wouldn't go to crazy but it's reasonable to have a canvas for the background (which is drawn once and you don't clear) and another for the other objects.

Comment: What about if you're drawing large sprites with requestAnimationFrame? Do you think 1 large sprite with multiple canvas` using that same sprite is better? Or do you think slicing the sprite and then loading the images each as their own canvas is better?  My spritesheet is roughly 1500x1000 incase you're wondering :P

Answer (score 3):

Do some testing, I've found that performance of the canvas varies depending on what specifically you're trying to do, but there are some general rules which you have to balance

-The fewer drawImage calls the better

-The smaller the area you're drawing the better

-drawing a whole image without slicing a piece out or scaling it is fastest

-the more transformations you apply to the canvas the slower it will be

So it really depends on your situation. If you're drawing 6 10x10 squares out your whole 1000x1600 image it's probably worth it to just draw the smaller pieces, but if you've got to cut them out of the larger image (using drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)) you may find it's still faster to draw the large image. There's not really a "best way" you've just got to test different things out.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Are you saying having a large sprite sheet and using it for each new drawImage is essentially faster? Or should I split the large sprite sheet up into individual images and give them their own canvas` instead. Reason I ask is because my spritesheet is around 1500x1000 and I have multiple images I need in there that need to be rendered with requestAnimationFrame.. Not sure if I use the sprite sheet or just slice the images and load them in.  Both ways I will use the same amount of drawImage, except the sprite way has larger canvas dimensions. Not sure :(

Comment: I would try out different methods and see which works best. If you have many small sprites, you almost certainly don't want to load each one  over http as it's own image, but what might end up being fastest overall is to load you master sprite sheet then cut each sprite / frame out onto it's own canvas so you don't have to slice the sprite out each time you draw it. The general idea is to do the more expensive operations once.

Comment: That's a great idea instead of redrawing the entire sprite multiple times and just slicing portions of it! Holy crap, thank you.